# ListView Bitmap

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I've been trying to display Bitmaps from my drawable folder, resize them (This part works just fine) and put them in a Listview, but when I run my code nothing appears...

Here it is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView image;
Bitmap[] data;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    data=new Bitmap[4];

    calculateInSampleSize size=new calculateInSampleSize();
    data[0]=(size.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_image1,100,100));
    data[1]=(size.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_image2,100,100));
    data[2]=(size.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_image3,100,100));
    data[3]=(size.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_image4,100,100));

    Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this,R.layout.pager_item,data);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
Bitmap[] dataSource;
LayoutInflater minflater;
Activity parentActivity;
int itemLayout;


// constructor for adapter
public Adapter (Activity activity, int layout, Bitmap[] ds){
    parentActivity = activity;
    itemLayout = layout;
    dataSource = ds;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView view;

    if(convertView!=null){
        view=(ImageView)convertView;
    }
    else{
        view=(ImageView)minflater.inflate(itemLayout,parent,false);
        view.setImageBitmap(dataSource[position]);

    }


    return view;
}
```

Of course I have a layout with a ListView in it and another one with an ImageView (pager_item.XML)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Modify your adapter like:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataSource.length;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public Bitmap getItem(int position) {
    return dataSource[position];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning 0 in

```
 @Override
public int getCount() {
  return 0;
}
```

You should return

```
dataSource.length;
```

and in

```
  @Override
 public Bitmap getItem(int position) {
return null;
 }
```

You should return

```
  return dataSource[position];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did both of you answers, but my app would crash whenever I launched it.

I changed a few things :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view=null;

    if(convertView!=null){
        view=convertView;
    }
    else{
        view= minflater.inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(dataSource[position]);

    }


    return view;
}
```

and I added this in my constructor:

```
minflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Thank you !